# If $F$ is a diffeomorphism, then $F_*(p)$ is an isomorphism - proof explanation

Tags: manifolds, proof-explanation

From Tu's book:

[image]

I do not see why this proves that $F$ and $G$ are isomorphisms. How does this prove bijectivity? Is there a theorem on isomorphisms that I am missing?

Comment: well, $F_\ast$ and $G_\ast$ are a priori linear maps of vector spaces, and the calculation shows that their composition yields the identity linear map in both possible ways. It's a statement of linear algebra (or the definition of *isomorphism* of vector spaces) that then $F_\ast$ and $G_\ast$ are indeed isomorphisms and moreover their respective inverses.

Comment: What is your definition of isomorphism ?

Comment: @N.H. Bijective linear maps

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Maybe I should have said that an isomorphism is, for me, a bijective linear map. Could you say what "statement of linear algebra" is that and where can I find it?

Comment: Ok. If $f : V \to W$ and $g : W \to V$ are linear maps with $g \circ f = id_V$, what can you say about $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: @N.H. Of course, Duh... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, $F_∗$ and $G_∗$ are a priori linear maps of vector spaces, and the calculation shows that their composition yields the identity linear map in both possible ways. It's a statement of linear algebra (or the definition of isomorphism of vector spaces) that then $F_∗$ and $G_∗$ are indeed isomorphisms and moreover their respective inverses.

– Sebastian Schulz

Answer (score 0):

$F_*$ is an isomorphism if it is linear and bijective. Its linearity is proved in the exercise (Exercise 8.3). Also, it is bijective iff it has an inverse. So for any point $p \in N$, we claim that $F_*$ has the inverse $F^{-1}_{*,p} \equiv G_{*, F(p)}: T_{F(p)}M \to T_pN$ and show that this is exactly the case by using Theorem 8.5. As $F_*$ has an inverse, it is a bijective function. Then it follows that $F_*$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

(1) $\quad (G \circ F)_* = G_* \circ F_* = 1_{T_pN}$ 
(2) $\quad (F \circ G)_* = F_* \circ G_* = 1_{T_pM}$

Since the identity map $1_{T_pN}$ is an isomorphism, (1) tells us that so is $G_* \circ F_*$. If there exists two elements $n_1, n_2$ in N such that $F_*(n_1)=F_*(n_2)$, then the image of $\{n_1,n_2\}$ under $(G \circ F)_*$ contains only one element, which contradicts our assumption that $(G \circ F)_* = 1_{T_pN}$ since the image of $\{n_1,n_2\}$ under $1_{T_pN}$ has two elements. Hence $F_*$ must necessarily be injective.

Additionally, if $(G \circ F)_*$ is a surjection like the identity function, then $N\subseteq Im(\: (G \circ F)_* \: ) \subseteq Im(G_*)$ implies that $G_*$ is also surjective.

Similarily from (2) we get that $F_*$ must be surjective and $G_*$ must be injective. Thus $F_*$ and $G_*$ are bijections.